# Let iter be an std::iterator. Is there any difference between std::next(iter,1) and ++iter?

Tags: c++, iterator

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

    // implementation 1:
    for(auto iter = v.begin(); iter !=v.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // implementation 2:
    for(auto iter = v.begin(); iter !=v.end(); iter = std::next(iter, 1))
        std::cout << *iter;
    std::cout << std::endl;       
}
```

As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/S6nX3g) implementation 1 and implementation 2 produce the same output. Is this always the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there is no difference. Both will advance the iterator one step.

Just to give one example where it might matter, let's say we want to print the second element of a range, we can't write something like `++b.begin()` since we can't apply `++` to an rvalue.

Here a code example.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 2> a = {2, 4};

    //std::cout << *(++a.begin()); // This will fail
    std::cout << *std::next(a.begin());
}
```

If we uncomment the first output line gcc says

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:8:29: error: lvalue required as increment operand
    8 |     std::cout << *(++a.begin());
      |                      ~~~~~~~^~
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fnc6QUgyze6ZOGK2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `iter = std::next(iter, 1)` is equivalent to `++iter`.

The only difference between `std::next(iter, 1)` and `++iter` i can think of is that `std::next` doesn't modify the iterator it returns the copy of resultant iterator.

Also `std::next` is very useful in generic context where `iterator` can be `random access` , `forward` etc. it will use most appropriate way to advance the iterator.

Comment: Some iterators may not support `++` but may still work with `std::next` and `std::advance`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I thought all iterators must support `++`, is that not true? It will not neccesarily work on an rvalue though.